# Gradle - Java code generation based on XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, gradle, ant

I am working on migration of Ant project to Gradle project.

As part of the Ant tool, java code was generated based on the XML file using XSL Transformation.

```
    <target name="logevents" if="logevents-defined">

    <!-- generate the java source -->
    <xslt basedir="${events-dir}" destdir="${gen-dir}/logevents" extension=".java" style="${stylesheet-dir}/logging/events-java.xsl" classpathref="xsl.classpath">
        <include name="**/*.xml" />
    </xslt>
</target>
```

I need to achieve the same in the Gradle tool.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the ANT task and relevant snippets from your build.xml. Don't just give a general description of what you are doing, show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
repositories{ 
mavenCentral() 
} 

configurations{ 
xslt 
} 

dependencies{ 
xslt "net.sf.saxon:saxon:8.7" 
} 

test << { 

 ant.xslt(in: 'C:/testng-results.xml', 
          style: 'C:/testng-results.xsl', 
          out:   'C:/index.java', 
          classpath: configurations.xslt.asPath 
 ) 
}
```

Reference: http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Help-calling-Ant-task-in-Gradle-for-xslt-transform-td3337068.html